# ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 - Signed LogoutRequest

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We have now implemented your excellent Identity Saml2 package for several of our customers.

However, one of our customers has written to us as follows:

> LogoutRequests need to be signed (mandatory), and I need to add the
> certificate you are signing with into the metadata to verify that it
> was [your application] that signed it.
>
> The same certificate is also used for signing the AuthnRequest (but
> that is optional but preferred)

We do not know what to do about this. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

In case it helps, following is in our application web.config for this customer:

```
<add key="SamlSpSettings:entityid" value="https://fmcentralqa.csu.edu.au/sisfm-enquiry" />
<add key="SamlSpSettings:acs"      value="https://fmcentralqa.csu.edu.au/SISfm-Enquiry/CSU/saml.aspx" />

<add key="SamlIdpSettings:entityid"  value="https://idpqa.csu.edu.au/idp/shibboleth" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:loginurl"  value="https://idpqa.csu.edu.au/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:logouturl" value="https://idpqa.csu.edu.au/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO" />

<add key="SamlIdpSettings:signercert1" value="...................." />

<add key="SamlIdpSettings:saml2sessionindex" value="http://schemas.itfoxtec.com/ws/2014/02/identity/claims/saml2sessionindex" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:saml2nameidformat" value="http://schemas.itfoxtec.com/ws/2014/02/identity/claims/saml2nameidformat" />

<add key="SamlIdpSettings:uid"          value="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:emailaddress" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:name"         value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:givenname"    value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:surname"      value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" />
<add key="SamlIdpSettings:groups"       value="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that the SAML 2.0 standard require the `LogoutRequest` to be signed.

You need a certificate for the application and to configure the certificate.

- In the config file:
  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L16
- And load the configured certificate:
  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L35

You can also load the certificate by `thumbprint` from the machines Certificate Store.

```
saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, Configuration["Saml2:SigningCertificateThumbprint"]);
```